# relative clause with incident

Tags: relative-clauses

I'd like to know which relative clause is used to when I want to speak about an incident.

For example, I've seen this sentence

"we've had countless incidents where cattle and animal stock have become diseased"

If is it correct, why do you use where?

Thank you

Comment: Because it avoids saying incidents in which, which some people find old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how helpful this is, but the OED says "where" can also mean "in which" when introducing an additional statement, and certainly you could substitute "in which" for "where" in your example. Yes it's correct, and perfectly understandable. Here's the relevant entry, with attestations:

I particularly like the 1584 spelling of *where* as *quhair*

> b. Introducing an additional statement (cf. 7b): In or at which; and
>   there; hence, †whereupon, and then.
>
> c1500   Melusine (1895) 238   She consyderyng the daunger where bothe
>   she & her peple had be
>
> 1584   King James VI & I Ess. Prentise Poesie sig. Kv   Ignorants
>   obdurde, quhair wilfull errour lyis
>
> 1597 Shakespeare Richard II v. ii. 5   Yorke. Where did I leaue? Du.
>   At that sad stop my Lord, Where rude misgouerned hands..Threw dust..on
>   king Richards head.
>
> 1692   tr. C. de Saint-Évremond Misc. Ess. 98  There is no life so
>   regular, where particular Actions don't sometimes exceed the general
>   habit and conduct.
>
> 1792   Jrnl. House of Commons 2 Apr. 47 641/2   In a Case where the
>   Officers had broken into a Bedchamber.
>
> 1887   W. P. Frith Autobiogr. I. xxi. 284   It is difficult to put
>   one's finger on the precise spot where confidence merges into conceit.

Source: OED(dot)com